# Android - Camera.open() returns Null only on Samsung S3

Tags: android, camera

I've spent several hours digging around for a solution to this problem, but to no avail.

I establish a camera with :

```
        if(camera == null){
            Log.d("CamTest", "Attempting to establish camera");
            camera = Camera.open();
            Log.d("CamTest", "Established Camera");
        }else{
            Log.d("CamTest","already had a camera? Releasing");
            camera.release();
            Log.d("CamTest","already had a camera? Released; Opening");
            camera = Camera.open();
            Log.d("CamTest","already had a camera? Opened");
```

Inside of an onCreate function. I also have a teardown function that looks like:

```
     if (recording) {
         recorder.stop();
         recorder.reset();
         recording = false;
         Log.d("CamTest", "recording reset");
     }
     if(recorder!=null){
         recorder.release();
         recorder = null;
        Log.d("CamTest", "Recorder Released");
     }
     if(camera!=null){
         camera.stopPreview();
         camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
         camera.release();
         camera = null;
         Log.d("CamTest", "Camera Released");
     }
```

inside of an onStop function.

The first time I tap through the app everything works fine (that is, navigate to the fragment that uses the camera, then press the "back" button). I get the (expected) output of:

```
    Attempting to establish camera
    Established Camera
    Recorder Released
    Camera Released
```

However if I immediately re-enter the camera-related fragment I crash with:

```
    Attempting to establish camera
    Fail to connect to camera service
    Camera.open() returned: null (this is generated by a Log I put in)
```

My permissions in AndroidManifest are also fine.

My understanding is that Camera.open() returns null when either: there is no back facing camera OR the back facing camera is currently in use by another application. The curiosity is that I'm certain that camera.release() is being called, as shown by the above log. Perhaps even more curious: this bug only occurs on a physical Samsung S3 (works on an emulated S3, and on other physical testing devices)

My inclination is that this is a hardware issue since it appears to work on other devices, but I'd very much appreciate getting opinions.